# Page transitions issue [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, transition

I have an app with bottom navbar. I can navigate between pages through the navbar. My problem is when i go to another page (not a button for this page on navbar) navbar disappears. I used that code below when click button and go to another page. But as i said navbar dissappears. I want navbar always stay.

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => ProgrammingScreen()));
```

*I tried PageView widget but i could'nt navigate pages from buttons. How can i solve this problem?*

Answer (score 0):

One option is to all those screens be in the page view widget.
But another thing you can do is put the exact same bottom nav bar in the new pushed screen and if the user selects an option. You can use Navigator.pop() and then navigate to the pageView with the selected option